# List of pairs of strings initialization in constructor

Tags: gcc, std-pair, c++98, stdlist

I have two classes, the scheduler and the cshw class. The constructor of the scheduler requires `std::list < std::pair<std::string, std::string> > names`. The CSHW class inherits from the scheduler and in the constructor of the cshw class i do `cshw::cshw():scheduler ({std::make_pair("mfp", "MFP") }){` i get a symbol not found error. 
I basically need to pass a list of pairs of strings to the scheduler constructor, this works in c++11 but i am facing this problem only in c++98

```
#ifndef SCHEDULER_H_
#define SCHEDULER_H_

#include <list>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

class scheduler {
public:
               std::list < std::pair<std::string, std::string>  > names;
               scheduler(std::list < std::pair<std::string, std::string> > names);
               virtual ~scheduler();
};

class cshw : public scheduler{
public:
               std::list < std::pair<std::string, std::string>  > m_szPanelNames;
               cshw();
               virtual ~cshw();
};

scheduler::scheduler(std::list < std::pair<std::string, std::string> > pnames) {
               names = pnames;
}

scheduler::~scheduler() {
}

cshw::cshw():
                              scheduler ({std::make_pair("mfp", "MFP") }){
}

cshw::~cshw() {
               // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
#endif /* SCHEDULER_H_ */
```

I get a constructor does not match error for the scheduler. I think this is caused by me trying to initialize a list pair as an argument. 
what is the way to pass a list of pairs as an argument in c++98 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add helper method in `cshw` which generates the list:

```
class cshw : public scheduler{
public:
               std::list < std::pair<std::string, std::string>  > m_szPanelNames;
               cshw();
               virtual ~cshw();

              // added
              std::list< std::pair<std::string,std::string> > genList()
              {
                  std::list< std::pair<std::string,std::string> > l;
                  l.push_back(std::make_pair("mfp","MFP"));
                  return l;
              }
};
```

then pass its result as param for `scheduler` on initialization list:

```
cshw::cshw():
   scheduler ( genList() ) 
{;}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/--QCMv)